# Ожидание анимации в javafx, последовательность действий

Tags: java, javafx, анимация, timeline

Есть простенькая игра на java fx. Там всего одна кнопка "Бросить кубик". Идет анимация через Timeline в 800 ms. Там меняются 6 изображений кубика. (Если углублятся прям, то в цикле у ImageView - DisableProperty текущего и след. меняются на true и false соответственно). Но! Еще до анимации, у меня вычисляются очки. А анимация там только для того, чтобы показать видимость, что кубик бросается (естественно последняя итерация дает правильную картинку, которая была вычислена еще до `timeline.play()`). 
Теперь вопрос: Последовательность вызовов -

```
ПоказатьАнимацию(); 
Перерисовать очки();
```

А на деле же очки начисляются еще до того как заканчивается анимация. Поэтому хочется понять как же сделать так, чтобы было последовательно: сначала заканчивается timeline, а потом выполняется следующая инструкция, а не все вместе. Из того что пробовал: новый Thread (ну это прям костыль), который ждет сначала эти 800 ms, а потом делает `Label.setText(player.getScore())`. Но в `new Thread`, как оказалось менять `Label` нельзя и я попробовал `Platform.runLater()` - тоже безрезультатно, анимация просто перестает идти. Ну и последнее -

```
timeline.play;
while(true){
    if(timeline.getStatus() == Animation.Status.STOPPED)
    break;
}
Label.setText(player.getScore();
```

Тут приложение вообще зависает.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `я попробовал Platform.runLater() - тоже безрезультатно` - должно работать, покажите как именно пробовали.

Comment: Вообще, приведите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример через `Timeline` и `Platform.runLater()`:

```
package sample;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Random random = new Random();

        Label label = new Label();
        label.setFont(new Font(48));

        int delay = 50;
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();

        // количество циклов на 5 секунд
        timeline.setCycleCount(5*1000/delay);

        KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(delay),
                event -> Platform.runLater(() ->
                        label.setText(String.format("%02d", random.nextInt(100))))
        );

        // При завершении установить заранее известное "случайное" число
        timeline.setOnFinished(event -> Platform.runLater(() -> label.setText("66")));

        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);

        Button button = new Button("Roll!");
        button.setOnAction(event -> timeline.play());

        VBox group = new VBox(button, label);

        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 300, 275);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, что если убрать `Platform.runLater` в `KeyFrame`, то не будет изменяться значение пока "кубик" катится, если убрать `Platform.runLater` в `setOnFinished`, то не будет установлено окончательное значение.

Comment: Вопрос решен, помогло, спасибо. Нужна была лишь строчка отсюда setOnFinished. Не знал про такой метод. Не догадался почему-то убрать в отдельный метод Platform.runLater(). Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, вы можете отметить его принятым (поставить галку рядом с ним).

Comment: У меня еще один вопрос сразу назрел. Наверное надо было написать это заранее. У меня контроллер с FXML, и отдельный класс AnimationHandler ( со статическими методами, отвечает за всю анимацию) . Все анимации я последовательно вызываю из Controller так: AnimationHandler.throwCube(); if(bonus) AnimationHandler.chargeBonus(); итд. Но все они выполняются одновременно не дожидаясь друг друга. А мне надо сделать паузу для пользователя

Comment: @НиколайХазов, лучше отдельный вопрос задать с примером кода.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать Task в связке с textproperty() для Label

```
DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
label_info.textProperty().bind(downloadTask.messageProperty());

Thread th = new Thread(downloadTask);
th.setDaemon(true);
th.start();
```

Класс расширяемый Task-ом

```
public class DownloadTask extends Task<Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        int x = 0;
        while(true){
        updateMessage("какое то сообщение " + x);
        x++;
    }
}
```

Но тогда, вам придётся переносить все вычисления в метод call(), НО!
Любой класс наследуемый от DownloadTask получит доступ к методу updateMessage, если вынести его в отдельный метод

```
public void update_messageForAll(String x){
    updateMessage("какое то сообщение " + x);
}
```

JavaFX не очень хороша для многопотока...

Comment: `JavaFX не очень хороша для многопотока...` - да ладно. Это все равно что написать, что java не очень хороша для многопоточности.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void afterAnimation() {
    //do something
}

timeline.setOnFinished( e -> {
    afterAnimation();
} );
```